# Simple request for help to autostart mining at boot time

Tags: raspbian

I'm really struggling to get something as simple as this to work. I've tried using rc.local, but for some reason the program doesn't seem to be starting, and I believe it would try to start before the desktop is up and running anyway.

I'm using the legacy 32-bit version of Raspberry Pi OS (Debian Bullseye) for a Pi 4.

I'd like a new terminal window to start up with the following command after the desktop has started at reboot time:

sudo /root/cpuminer-multi/cpuminer -parameters for the miner etc

It would be nice to have the terminal window visible, so that I can check on its status via VNC periodically.

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP seems deeply confused.

Comment: I am confused, that's why I'm asking for help :-)

Comment: How would I go about starting a terminal window with the commands above after the Pi started? I assumed it would be a simple task, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: If all you're going to do is run this `cpuminer` command - why are you even running the GUI/X-Windows? Have you considered running your RPi "headless", and just use SSH to log in? This is why your question is **so bad** - it's like you know absolutely nothing about anything. :-|